# Is there any way to break out of a foreach loop?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, break

I am using the R package `foreach()` with `%dopar%` to do long (~days) calculations in parallel. I would like the ability to stop the entire set of calculations in the event that one of them produces an error. However, I have not found a way to achieve this, and from the documentation and various forums I have found no indication that this is possible. In particular, `break()` does not work and `stop()` only stops the current calculation, not the whole `foreach` loop.

Note that I cannot use a simple for loop, because ultimately I want to parallelize this using the doRNG package.

Here is a simplified, reproducible version of what I am attempting (shown here in serial  with `%do%`, but I have the same problem when using `doRNG` and `%dopar%`). Note that in reality I want to run all of the elements of this loop (here 10) in parallel.

```
library(foreach)
myfunc <- function() {
  x <- foreach(k = 1:10, .combine="cbind", .errorhandling="stop") %do% {
    cat("Element ", k, "\n")
    Sys.sleep(0.5) # just to show that stop does not cause exit from foreach
    if(is.element(k, 2:6)) {
      cat("Should stop\n")
      stop("Has stopped")
    }
    k
  }
  return(x)
}
x <- myfunc()
# stop() halts the processing of k=2:6, but it does not stop the foreach loop itself.
# x is not returned. The execution produces the error message
# Error in { : task 2 failed - "Has stopped"
```

What I would like to achieve is that the entire foreach loop can be exited immediately upon some condition (here, when the `stop()` is encountered).

I have found no way to achieve this with `foreach`. It seems that I would need a way to send a message to all the other processes to make them stop too.

If not possible with `foreach`, does anyone know of alternatives? I have also tried to achieve this with `parallel::mclapply`, but that does not work either.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods base

other attached packages:
[1] foreach_1.4.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_3.0.0  iterators_1.0.6
```

Comment: Would it not be possible to use `for` instead?

Comment: No, because ultimately I want to parallelize this using the doRNG package. (Sorry I didn't make that clear in my original post: I've edited it to make this explicit.)

Comment: Based on your other comments, you might want to have each sub-process able to set a 'flag' object on failure, and make that object available  for reading by all sub-processes.  They'd all have to have some internal breakpoint or equivalent which regularly checks the value of the 'flag,' so they all can self-terminate.

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you want an *impatient* version of the "stop" error handling.  You could implement that by writing a custom combine function, and arranging for `foreach` to call it as soon as each result is returned.  To do that you need to:

- Use a backend that supports calling `combine` on-the-fly, like `doMPI` or `doRedis`
- Don't enable `.multicombine`
- Set `.inorder` to `FALSE`
- Set `.init` to something (like `NULL`)

Here's an example that does that:

```
library(foreach)
parfun <- function(errval, n) {
  abortable <- function(errfun) {
    comb <- function(x, y) {
      if (inherits(y, 'error')) {
        warning('This will leave your parallel backend in an inconsistent state')
        errfun(y)
      }
      c(x, y)
    }
    foreach(i=seq_len(n), .errorhandling='pass', .export='errval',
            .combine='comb', .inorder=FALSE, .init=NULL) %dopar% {
      if (i == errval)
        stop('testing abort')
      Sys.sleep(10)
      i
    }
  }
  callCC(abortable)
}
```

Note that I also set the error handling to "pass" so `foreach` will call the combine function with an error object.  The `callCC` function is used to return from the `foreach` loop regardless of the error handling used within `foreach` and the backend.  In this case, `callCC` will call the `abortable` function, passing it a function object that is used force `callCC` to immediately return.  By calling that function from the combine function we can escape from the `foreach` loop when we detect an error object, and have `callCC` return that object.  See `?callCC` for more information.

You can actually use `parfun` without a parallel backend registered and verify that the `foreach` loop "breaks" as soon as it executes a task that throws an error, but that could take awhile since the tasks are executed sequentially.  For example, this takes 20 seconds to execute if no backend is registered:

```
print(system.time(parfun(3, 4)))
```

When executing `parfun` in parallel, we need to do more than simply break out of the `foreach` loop: we also need to stop the workers, otherwise they will continue to compute their assigned tasks.  With `doMPI`, the workers can be stopped using `mpi.abort`:

```
library(doMPI)
cl <- startMPIcluster()
registerDoMPI(cl)
r <- parfun(getDoParWorkers(), getDoParWorkers())
if (inherits(r, 'error')) {
  cat(sprintf('Caught error: %s\n', conditionMessage(r)))
  mpi.abort(cl$comm)
}
```

Note that the cluster object can't be used after the loop aborts, because things weren't properly cleaned up, which is why the normal "stop" error handling doesn't work this way.

Comment: +1 for the comment, and for your book that helped me a lot :)

Comment: I am a bit confused about what is causing the early exit if it is no longer a stop() in the combine function comb(). I presume the stop() in the foreach is triggering the call of comb(). Is it then errfun() which causes the early exit? But what is errfun()? It is not explicitly defined (and the name is arbitrary). Also, when I run parfun(6,12) with %dopar% and doMPI on 4 cores, the execution continues for i=5,7,8,9 (verified using the sink() approach in my answer below), so I'm not sure it really is stopping early when run in parallel.

Comment: The `stop` in the `foreach` loop simply causes an error object to be returned as the task result to the master.  Since error handling is "pass", `foreach` passes it to the combine function, and does so immediately due to the specified options.  If the combine function calls `errfun`, the combine function won't return to its caller, but to `callCC`.  But as I say in the revised answer, that has no effect on the workers, which is why mpi.abort is needed.

Comment: I believe the additional output that you see from the workers is because they continue as normal until `mpi.abort` is called.

Comment: Actually, the additional output is produced after mpi.abort has been called (and several seconds after Caught error' is printed) and I see in "top" that the processes are still running. So although we are breaking out of the foreach loop (and thus preventing later workers from starting) the existing workers are not being stopped. So it seems that this approach does not allow me to instantly stop all workers on an error in one of them. I experimented with passing `cl` into the `foreach` loop and using `mpi.abort(cl$comm)` there, but (not surprisingly) this didn't work.

Comment: It stops almost instantly on my Linux machine using Rmpi 0.6.1 built with Open MPI 1.4.3.  When spawning 6 workers, the whole run takes about 2 seconds and I'm able to verify with "top" that everything was killed.  I don't know why mpi.abort isn't working for you.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but using `when()` you can avoid entering the loop if a condition is satisfied:

```
x <- foreach(k = 1:10, .combine="cbind", .errorhandling="stop") %:%
  when( !is.element(k, 2:6) ) %do%
  {
    cat("Element ", k, "\n")
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    k
  }
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot something: I think it's by design, that you cannot just stop the foreach loop. If you run the loop in parallel, each turn is processed independently, which means when you stop the entire loop for `k=2` it is not predictable if the process for `k=1` terminated already or is still running. Hence, using the `when()` condition gives you a deterministic result.

**EDIT 2:** Another solution considering your comment.

```
shouldStop <- FALSE
x <- foreach(k = 1:10, .combine="cbind", .errorhandling="stop") %do%
  {
    if( !shouldStop ){
      # put your time consuming code here
      cat("Element ", k, "\n")
      Sys.sleep(0.5)
      shouldStop <- shouldStop ||  is.element(k, 2:6)
      k
    }
  }
```

Using this solution, the processes which are running while the stop condition becomes true are still calculated to an end, but you avoid time consumption on all upcoming processes.

Comment: The problem is that I will only know whether I want to exit from the loop once I've done some of the calculations in the loop. Yet it's exactly these calculations which I want to parallelize with this loop. (In other words, the condition itself is time-consuming the calculate.)

Comment: EDIT 2 is a useful suggestion, but the way I run this is that the number of things to process is equal to the number of CPU cores available (10-50). Thus all processes are started simultaneously, and there are no future processes to avoid starting. As it is now, I must wait for all of these to finish before I get the error message from stop(). A work around would be for me to manually kill the entire program as soon as I see the message produced by cat() (in my post), but this is impractical because this is a long run (~1 day) and runs in the background on a remote machine.

Comment: This information changes the whole thing and should be mentioned in the original post. However, I must admit that in this case my ideas are limited. You could try to control your nodes directly using for example `clusterApply` from the `snow` package and call `stopCluster()` when the first job with the desired result is done. But be aware that calling `stopCluster()` from a slave process will not only give ugly errors. Additionally, the result will not return to the master. Maybe someone else has an idea how the result can be passed?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to break out of a loop, I write a small file to the disk when I've reached my terminal loop, then have all remaining iterations simply skip based on the existence of that file.

Checking if a file exists costs us less than a milisecond of computing time.

```
# 1.4 seconds to check if a file exists a million times
system.time(lapply(1:1e6, function(x) file.exists("checker.txt")))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.204   0.233   1.437
```

This is great when you don't have a fixed number of iterations or your process can finish before all of the iterations are complete (like a convergence, for example)

```
library(foreach)

alist <- foreach(i = 1:5000) %dopar% { 
  if(file.exists("checker.txt")) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    if(i = 20) {
      write("", "checker.txt") # write an empty file
    }
    return(i)
  }
}

file.remove("checker.txt")
```

The great thing about this is that even if your list is extremely long, if you just unlist() you only get the values.

```
> length(alist)
[1] 5000

> unlist(res)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Don't bother trying to break, instead, just "skip the rest"!

Comment: Brilliant - was stuck for a long time on this one. I used this method within a try/catch statement. When a subprocess generates an error, it skips the remaining iterations. And the script starts again the foreach loop with some modifications (not producing an error this time).

Comment: this is great! Thanks

Comment: Great idea. FYI there's an error in the example code: if (i = 20) should be if (i == 20)

Answer (score 1):

The answer I got from REvolution Technical support: "no--foreach doesn't currently have a way to stop all parallel computations on an error to any one".

Answer (score 0):

I am not having much luck getting `foreach` to do what I want, so here is a solution using the `parallel` package which seems to do what I want. I use the `intermediate` option in `mcparallel()` to pass results from my function, `do.task()`, immediately to the function `check.res()`. If `do.task()` throws an error, then this is used in `check.res()` to trigger calling `tools::pskill` to explicitly kill all workers. This might not be very elegant, but it works in the sense that it causes an instant stop of all worked. Furthermore, I can simply inherit all the variables I need for the processing in `do.task()` from the present environment. (In reality `do.task()` is a much more complex function requiring many variables to be passed in.)

```
library(parallel)

# do.task() and check.res() inherit some variables from enclosing environment

do.task <- function(x) {
  cat("Starting task", x, "\n")
  Sys.sleep(5*x)
  if(x==stopat) { 
    stop("Error in job", x) # thrown to mccollect() which sends it to check.res()
  }
  cat("  Completed task", x, "\n")
  return(10*x)
}

check.res <- function(r) { # r is list of results so far
  cat("Called check.res\n")
  sendKill <- FALSE
  for(j in 1:Njob) { # check whether need to kill
    if(inherits(r[[j]], 'try-error')) {
      sendKill <- TRUE
    }
  }
  if(sendKill) { # then kill all
    for(j in 1:Njob) {
      cat("Killing job", job[[j]]$pid, "\n") 
      tools::pskill(job[[j]]$pid) # mckill not accessible
    }
  }
}

Tstart <- Sys.time()
stopat <- 3
Njob <- 4
job <- vector("list", length=Njob)
for(j in 1:Njob) {
  job[[j]]<- mcparallel(do.task(j))
}
res <- mccollect(job, intermediate=check.res) # res is in order 1:Njob, regardless of how long jobs took
cat("Collected\n")
Tstop <- Sys.time()
print(difftime(Tstop,Tstart))
for(j in 1:Njob) {
  if(inherits(res[[j]], 'try-error')) {
    stop("Parallel part encountered an error")
  }
}
```

This gives the following screen dump and results for variable `res`

```
> source("exp5.R")
Starting task 1 
Starting task 2 
Starting task 3 
Starting task 4 
  Completed task 1 
Called check.res
Called check.res
  Completed task 2 
Called check.res
Called check.res
Called check.res
Killing job 21423 
Killing job 21424 
Killing job 21425 
Killing job 21426 
Called check.res
Killing job 21423 
Killing job 21424 
Killing job 21425 
Killing job 21426 
Called check.res
Killing job 21423 
Killing job 21424 
Killing job 21425 
Killing job 21426 
Collected
Time difference of 15.03558 secs
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : Parallel part encountered an error
> res
$`21423`
[1] 10

$`21424`
[1] 20

$`21425`
[1] "Error in do.task(j) : Error in job3\n"
attr(,"class")
[1] "try-error"
attr(,"condition")
<simpleError in do.task(j): Error in job3>

$`21426`
NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Steve Weston's original answer essentially answered this. But here is a slightly modified version of his answer which also preserves two additional features in the way I need them: (1) random number generation; (2) printing run-time diagnostics.

```
suppressMessages(library(doMPI))

comb <- function(x, y) {
  if(inherits(y, 'error')) {
    stop(y)
  }
  rbind(x, y) # forces the row names to be 'y'
}

myfunc <- function() {
  writeLines(text="foreach log", con="log.txt")
  foreach(i=1:12, .errorhandling='pass', .combine='comb', .inorder=FALSE, .init=NULL) %dopar% {
    set.seed(100)
    sink("log.txt", append=TRUE)
    if(i==6) {
      stop('testing abort')
    }
    Sys.sleep(10)
    cat("Completed task", i, "\n")
    sink(NULL)
    rnorm(5,mean=i)
  }
}

myerr <- function(e) {
  cat(sprintf('Caught error: %s\n', conditionMessage(e)))
  mpi.abort(cl$comm)
}

cl <- startMPIcluster(4)
registerDoMPI(cl)
r <- tryCatch(myfunc(), error=myerr)
closeCluster(cl)
```

When this file is sourced, it exits as intended with an error message

```
> source("exp2.R")
    4 slaves are spawned successfully. 0 failed.
Caught error: testing abort
[ganges.local:16325] MPI_ABORT invoked on rank 0 in communicator  with errorcode 0
```

The 'log.txt' files provides correct diagnostics up to the point of error, and then provides additional error information. Crucially, the execution of all tasks is halted as soon as the stop() in the foreach loop is encountered: it does not wait until the entire foreach loop has completed. Thus I only see the 'Completed task' message up to i=4. (Note that if Sys.sleep() is shorter, then later tasks may be started before the mpi.abort() is processed.)

If I change the stop condition to be "i==100", then the stop and hence the error is not triggered. The code successfully exists without an error message, and r is a 2D array with dimensions 12*5.

Incidentally, it seems that I don't actually need .inorder=FALSE (I think that just gives me a small speed increase in the event that an error is found).

Comment: I changed my answer because I discovered it was taking advantage of incorrect error handling in doMPI.  Executing `stop` in the combine function shouldn't abort foreach, and that is fixed in the development version of doMPI on R-forge, so your answer won't work when that is released.

Comment: If you don't set `.inorder=FALSE`, then the combine function won't be called until all previous tasks have been processed by the combine function.  So if the failing task isn't the very first task, it will take at least 10 seconds to abort in your example.